# Vt-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I imported a VM from Oracle and tried to open it.
When I try to run the VM, i get the following message:

> VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system. Your
>   64-bit guest will fail to detect a 64-bit CPU and will not be able to
>   boot.

As it can be seen from configuration, the VT-x is available on my machine:

[image]

Can someone tell me what else should I do in order to be able to start he VM, please?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried turning on VT-x on your motherboard/BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: the marked value from  attached screenshot doesn't mean  that the VT-x is active?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on what tool your using to run your VM,

e.g. Virtual box there is setting to enable Hardware virtualization for guest VM

Edited:

If you don't have hardware Virtualisation enable you can try with software Virtualisation this will impact performance

[image]

Comment: The acceleration tab from system option is grayed. I cannot access it.

Comment: Have you enabled it in Bios settings ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to perform modifications in BIOS as it is password protected but I was able to see that the Hardware Virtualization option is on "Disabled".

Answer (score 10):

You need to **Enable Virtual Hardware** in BIOS.

1. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> key at startup BIOS Setup.
2. Switch to the **Advanced Mode** tab then choose **CPU Configuration**
   option.
3. Scroll down to the **"Intel Virtualization Technology"** value, and then
   change `[Disabled]->[Enabled]`.
4. Save Changes and Exit.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I resolved this problem:

1. I restarted computer, disabled virtualization from BIOS, and started computer.
2. When I opened Virtualbox, nothing changed (the same error).
3. I restarted computer again, and enabled virtualization from BIOS, and started computer.
4. When I opened Virtualbox, guest OS started without problem.